# .NET deserialization of json fails if __type is not first in property list

Tags: c#, json

I send json objects to DotNet Service in format

```
{"__type":"EntityItem#ru.test.com","name":"sample"}
```

And on Net service i got object EntityItem and all good.

But if __type will not first in list properties then it's get error parsing object. Next version JSON crashes

```
{"name":"sample","__type":"EntityItem#ru.test.com"}
```

Does exists solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "type hints". Here is link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx
and qoute

```
Note that the type hint must appear first in the JSON representation. This is the only case where order of key/value pairs is important in JSON processing.
```

It's so sad.